# Excel Cell Comments import into SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, sql-server-2008-r2

Have found myself needing to import a spreadsheet that someone has been using as an adhoc database into SQL Server to build a proper application around it. Unfortunately the spreadsheet uses comments to record reasons for actions against numerous fields and I need to bring those into the DB too.

Can anyone recommend a fairly simple way or workflow for importing the comments into sql whilst maintaining a link to the original cell?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are at least two approaches.  Say column C has data and Comments.  Say column H  is un-used.  A macro could extract the comments from C and store them in H.

The other approach would have the macro extract the Comment from each cell and append the text to the data in that cell.

These changes to the worksheet would not have to be permanent.